# Getting Clicked Edit Value Item to Another page using jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

MySQL table name demo with below listed values peter and john with edit links

**Example**

```
Peter EDIT
John  EDIT
```

on clicking **edit** link i'm opening edit_name.php page. In edit_name.php i'm updating my clicked edited value with update button..

My requirement is in edit_name.php i should receive clicked name value

**for example**

If i click on peter edit button i should get peter value in edit_name.php file and if i click on john edit button i should get john value in edit_name.php etc..

please somebody help me in getting value of clicked in my edit_name.php file

**php code**

```
<div>
<?php 
    $sql="select * from demo";
    $data = $con->query($sql);
    if($data->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row = $data->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            $str = "" 
    ?>
    <div class="show_edit_page">
        <div>
            <?php echo $row['name'];?>
            <a href="#" class="ajax_edit" data-id="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">EDIT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php   
    }
    }
?>
</div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**Jquery Code**

jquery code to open edit_name.php file on clicking edit link

```
$('.show_edit_page').on('click','.ajax_edit',function(){
    var id = $(this).data('data-id');
    $('#content').load('edit_name.php');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could give the name as URL parameter to the load URL:

```
('.show_edit_page').on('click','.ajax_edit',function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $('#content').load('edit_name.php?name='+id); 
});
```

then catch the name parameter in edit_name.php file with:

```
$theName = $_REQUEST('name');
```

That should do...

Also the `.data` I would replace with `.attr` on line 2

Comment: Thank You So Much For ur valuable time and ur suggestion it was really helpful Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to update for accordingly.First you have to send that name via jQuery then you will receive that value in **PHP page**

```
$('.show_edit_page').on('click','.ajax_edit',function(){
    var id = $(this).data('data-id');
    var name = FetchNameValue; //Get this value using jQuery
    $('#content').load('edit_name.php?name='+name); //Send value to edit_name.php
});
```

Once you send that value to PHP page then change code at php side

Use `$_GET['name']` to get value of name in PHP page.

I hope this will help you in case you have any query please tell me know.